# How to enable line wrap in Xcode only for the console?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 with line wrapping disabled. In the editors, the code is not wrapped, but the console output is wrapped. I like it that way.

I just installed Xcode 11.5 on another Mac and I cannot recreate these settings there. If I toggle the "Wrap lines to editor width" option in the Settings menu, the setting affects both the editors and the console. Is there a way to set this option independently for these views? How can I recreate the behavior that I see in Xcode 11.3.1?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Xcode 13, it appears line wrapping is implemented independently per editor window. From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes): "Xcode’s console now supports toggling line wrapping through the Editor > Wrap Lines menu item. (3669727)"

I have several editors open at the moment, including the console, and the wrapping attribute is specific to each window.